# How to use the value of a combo box that is outside of an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

On my PHP web page I have three forms with input fields, each with its own submit button. Additionally there is one combo box on that page, outside of any form. This combo box should be used by any of the three forms as soon as the user clicks a submit button.

```
<html>
...
<select name="app">...</select>
...
<form name="form1" action="up1.php" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form name="form2" action="up2.php" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form name="form3" action="up3.php" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
</html>
```

How can read and post the current combo box's value together with the other values of a form, even if the combo box is not within the form?

Comment: Some code would be helpfull. Also what technology are you going to use to "read" the form? javascript, php, asp.net etc..

Comment: @skyfoot: ok, I have added some code samples and mention that I use PHP.

Comment: Is it an option to also use javascript?

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, to use JS would be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="app">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<form onsubmit="gatherComboBox(this)" action="" method="">
<!-- form content -->
</form>
<script>
  function gatherComboBox(f){
    var s=document.getElementById('app'), i=document.createElement('input');
    s=s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    i.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    i.setAttribute('name','app');
    i.setAttribute('value',s);
    f.appendChild(i);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, this could be an alternative:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Copy from select to hidden field</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            copy();
            $("#combo").change(function() {
                copy();
            }); 
        }); 
        function copy()
        {
            $(".value-from-combo").each(function() {
                $(this).val($("#combo option:selected").val());
            });   
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="combo">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <form method="get" name="form1" action="">
        <input name="copied1" class="value-from-combo" type="hidden" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <form method="get" name="form2" action="">
        <input name="copied2" class="value-from-combo" type="hidden" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <form method="get" name="form3" action="">
        <input name="copied3" class="value-from-combo" type="hidden" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```